# how to install nfdump?

Tags: package-management

How to install downladed nfdump from  the same machine; I have try  wget http://noc.ws.nsrc.org/downloads/nfdump-1.6.10.tar.gz or http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfdump/files/latest/download but I couldnt download from them. is there any way to install it manual from downladed zip file which is in file system in the machine.

Comment: what do you mean "couldn't download"?

Comment: Why not just do `sudo apt-get install nfdump`?

Comment: i am using proxy server

Comment: administrator@DIS-MON-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install nfdump
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbi1 librrd4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbi1 librrd4 nfdump
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 402 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,890 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
0% [Connecting to tz.archive.ubuntu.com (197.155.77.2)]
 this what i get

Comment: So configure the proxy so you can  use apt-get?

Comment: I have did,it does end like above

Comment: Err http://tz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe checkinstall amd64 1.6.2-4ubuntu1
  Cannot initiate the connection to tz.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2c0f:fe40:8001:10::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2c0f:fe40:8001:10::2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://tz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/checkinstall/checkinstall_1.6.2-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to tz.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2c0f:fe40:8001:10::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 3):

Install it using the CLI :

```
sudo apt-get install nfdump
```

Or using Ubuntu Software Center :

[image: Install via the software center]

On 15.04 this will install version 1.6.12

---

You can also compile it to get the latest version (at the moment 1.6.13):

1. Download:

   ```
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nfdump/stable/nfdump-1.6.13/nfdump-1.6.13.tar.gz 
   tar zxvf nfdump-1.6.13.tar.gz 
   cd nfdump-1.6.13
   ```
2. Compile:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install flex
   ./configure
   make
   ```
3. Install it using `checkinstall`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   Why `checkinstall`? That's why:

   > CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by "make install" or
   >   equivalent.   It creates a .deb package and adds it to the installed
   >   packages database.   This allows easy package removal later. —  [Ubuntu  Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

---

<sup>Successfully tested on my Ubuntu 15.04.</sup>